# Distribution function of a random variable $\xi>0$, $\mathrm{P}(\xi>x+y \mid \xi>x)=\mathrm{P}(\xi>y), \forall x, y>0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

I'm trying to teach my self the first 10 chapters of the book out of interest:
"Leonid Koralov, Yakov G. Sinai - Theory of probability and random processes".

**Problem:**
Find the distribution function of a random variable $\xi$ which takes positive values and satisfies $\mathrm{P}(\xi>x+y \mid\xi>x)=\mathrm{P}(\xi>y), \forall x, y > 0$.

I figure I have to use some sort of conditional probability rule, like $P(A\mid B)=P(AB)/P(B)$, to get $P(\xi>x+y \mid \xi>x)=\frac{P(\xi>x+y \cap \xi>y)}{p(\xi>x)}=P(\xi>y)$, but I do not believe this to be right.

We know that $x+y>x, x+y>y$, since $x,y>0$. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the conditional probability rule. What you want to use is:
$$
\mathbb P[A | B] = \frac{\mathbb P[A \cap B]}{\mathbb P[B]}. 
$$
In this case, since $\xi > 0$, we know $\{\xi > x\} \subset \{\xi > x+y\}$ for $x,y > 0$, so this means:
$$
\mathbb P[\xi > y] = \mathbb P[\xi > x + y|\xi > x] = \frac{\mathbb P[\{\xi > x + y\} \cap \{\xi > x\}]}{\mathbb P[ \xi > x]} = \frac{\mathbb P[\xi > x+y]}{\mathbb P[\xi > x]}
$$
(by the way, why do we know $\mathbb P[\xi > x] \neq 0$?) So this tells us:
$$
\mathbb P[\xi > x]\mathbb P[\xi > y] = \mathbb P[\xi > x+y].
$$
Now, let's say that $r = \mathbb P[\xi > 1]$. Can you figure out $\mathbb P[\xi > x]$ for $x \in \mathbb N$? What about $x \in \mathbb Q$? What about $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Thank you very much! I also remembered the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, which helped quite a bit ;)

Comment: For others: I used $r=P(\xi>1)$, in the following way. The CDF is given as $P(\xi \leq x)$, thus $P(\xi \leq 1) = 1-r$. We know this property should go to 1, as x goes to infinity; thus requiring some kind of exp. decay. That got me into thinking about the exponential distribution. Thus, the answer from me would be the **exponential distribution**.

Comment: It is indeed exponential distribution, but the fact that $\mathbb P[\xi \leq x] \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ doesn’t necessarily mean that the CDF decays *exponentially*; for example, $\mathbb P[X > x] = x^{-\alpha}$ ($\alpha > 0$) is a CDF on $[1,\infty)$ that decays *polynomially*.

Comment: Another thing: you’re right to think about the memorylessness of the exponential distribution. What this problem shows is that the exponential distribution is the *only* distribution with memorylessness.

Comment: Yes, I might have been a quick on the comment, since I was happy to have solved it :).

Comment: My thinking started with considering the hint, you gave me:
$r=P(\xi>1)$. I considered the integers and the fact that the infinite sum of these probabilities should converge. The only way to have this, is with exponential decay. From there, my mind, thankfully, remembered the exponential distribution. Then I showed that, the only distribution to fulfil
$\mathbb{P}[\xi>x] \mathbb{P}[\xi>y]=\mathbb{P}[\xi>x+y]$,
Was the exponential distribution. I used the survival function approach, which I had seen before.

I really appreciate you taking your time. Thank you **very** much.

Comment: I’m glad to have helped! But one question. When you say “…the infinite sum of these probabilities should converge. The only way to have this, is with exponential decay”, do you mean to say that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, then we must have $a_n = r^n$ for some $|r| < 1$? Because that’s not true: a simple example is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2} = \pi^2/6$. Exponential decay is great, and it has lots of useful applications, but (especially in probability theory) there are many other slower types of summable decay…

Comment: You're completely correct. I just mean that the sum should converge. Also: I'm new to posting on this forum; do you know why my post is "closed"? It says it need more details or clarity, but I can't really see what more to add to be honest :)

Comment: Honestly I'm a little puzzled by that myself. It's possible someone asked a similar question elsewhere on math.stackexchange but that's just my best guess.